# Antd first row default selection

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want my first row of Antd table to be selected as default upon loading.
https://ant.design/components/table

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, this code is available in the official ant design docs **[here](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-row-selection-and-operation)**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { Button, Table } from 'antd';
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
  },
];
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Edward King ${i}`,
    age: 32,
    address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`,
  });
}
const App = () => {
  const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const start = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    // ajax request after empty completing
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSelectedRowKeys([]);
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  };
  const onSelectChange = (newSelectedRowKeys) => {
    console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', newSelectedRowKeys);
    setSelectedRowKeys(newSelectedRowKeys);
  };
  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys,
    onChange: onSelectChange,
  };
  const hasSelected = selectedRowKeys.length > 0;
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          marginBottom: 16,
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" onClick={start} disabled={!hasSelected} loading={loading}>
          Reload
        </Button>
        <span
          style={{
            marginLeft: 8,
          }}
        >
          {hasSelected ? `Selected ${selectedRowKeys.length} items` : ''}
        </span>
      </div>
      <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Now in this case, you can control the selected elements through the `selectedRowKeys` state defined above.

So for instance, if you know the `key` of the element you want to select, regardless of its position you can just assign it:
`const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([default_keys]);`
(*replace the default_keys with the value/s you want to be selected*)

**Important Note**, this code is copied from the ant design documentation, therefore, you can remove the code that is not relevant to you.